# what is this amplify.module = function(whapp, module, config, construct, methods) {

Tags: jquery, module, kazoo

i was checking on code on kazoo UI platform so i found this code in one of its js file and when i search online regarding amplifyjs module then their is not link or content related this topic. does anyone have idea about what exactly is this?

```
/*!
 * Amplify Module
 *
 * Version: @VERSION
 * Released: @DATE
 * Source: http://amplifyjs.com/module
 *
 * Copyright 2010 appendTo LLC. (http://appendto.com/team)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL licenses.
 * http://appendto.com/open-source-licenses
 */
(function( amplify, $, undefined ) {
var modules = {};
amplify.module = function(whapp, module, config, construct, methods) {
```

Comment: I haven't ever used amplifyjs, but this looks like the constructor function to me

Comment: amplify.js is an ajax-wrapper

Comment: @Paradoxis, john Smith - i really appreciate both of your answer. i have bit idea about amplify that it provide ajax request and define and  subscribe and publish functionaries but my question was that what is amplify module. amplify consist three component right now : Request / Store and PUB/SUB what what is module i am not sure might be they were having this in their old version. having doubt about this. Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Amplify JS is a little framework created by AppendTo (former jQuery guys). As said before it allows pub/sub, request, store and also a little module architecture.

Unfortunately amplify.module is not supported by appendTo anymore. If you are interested in that module architecture I advise you to check this out https://github.com/2600hz/monster-ui .

If you have more questions please feel free to come on our IRC channel #2600hz or the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/2600hz-dev).